# Step Detection (Changepoint / Anomaly)

Tags: anomaly-detection, change-point

The problem I am trying to solve is detecting step changes in a multivariate dataset, where each feature is the market share for a certain category of companies. The data is not very noisy so I would imagine that solving this problem should not be too difficult. I show a sample of the data below, where each bar is the market share of that specific category of companies and each color is a different category of companies. The beginning and ending of the blue step changes should ideally be identified by an algorithm. [image] At first, I approached this as an outlier detection problem, and implemented most of the algorithms in the pyod library. Most algorithms struggle with consistently identifying the beginning of a step change and most of them actually target "point" anomalies more so than step changes. I have also tried approaching this problem as a changepoint detection problem, and implemented the ruptures library in python. This too fails to detect the beginning of steps, which is surprising since the step changes are so clear and obvious.

Am I approaching this problem incorrectly? Maybe this is neither an outlier detection task nor a changepoint detection task. I've looked into "step detection", which apparently is a subset of changepoint detection, although I have not found good ideas there besides CUSUM (which I have not yet implemented). This might be similar to the 2D task of edge detection within computer vision so maybe those filters could come in handy here.

Comment: This is a multiple changepoint detection problem for multivariate data, but most algorithms designed to solve it need longer stationary periods for reliable detection of all the changepoints.  If this example is typical of your data, have you considered just clustering the values (regardless of time stamp)?  It looks like the process jumps among a small number of clearly-defined, well-separated clusters.

Comment: The problem is that this is not a typical time series in the dataset. Different cuts of the dataset do not have such clearly defined steps. Some will have only one step, and some will have none at all. I will give the clustering a shot, because you're right, these steps are essentially clusters.

Comment: You can try a Hidden Markov Model, with 2 or 3 states

Comment: Are you wanting to detect the (majority) colour changes along the x-axis?  You could do this without an algorithm just by looking at the modal colour and then looking for when that changed.  As you said, there is very little noise in the data so this will be a) fast and b) accurate.  If this is merely a "nice" example and in reality it is much noisier, then you will need a categorical changepoint approach that takes into account that the probabilities must sum to 1.

Comment: I have not tried the HMM or modal method but a convolution filter seems to work well (for this example at least). Its interesting that a changepoint method was less accurate than a plain old filter in this example.